# Some of elasticsearch.yml configuration is not taking effect

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to set up following properties:

```
bootstrap:
    mlockall: true

index:
    warmer:
        enabled: false

    translog:
        interval: 10s
        flush_threshold_size: 1024mb

    gateway:
        local:
            sync: 10s


indices:
    memory:
        index_buffer_size: 50%
    store:
        throttle.type: none
```

I tried even :

```
bootstrap.mlockall: true

index.warmer.enabled: false

index.translog.interval: 10s

index.gateway.local.sync: 10s

index.translog.flush_threshold_size: 1024mb

indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 50%

indices.store.throttle.type: none
```

But `GET _cluster/settings` has empty output :

```
{
   "persistent": {},
   "transient": {}
}
```

`GET _settings` for all indices that where created afterwards show settings without these settings :

```
   "indexName": {
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1427893895234",
            "uuid": "lJsmOeOORdOuG7GHbFmmaw",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "version": {
               "created": "1050099"
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

And `GET _nodes/process` shows `"mlockall": false` ... Of course I restarted ES. Interesting thing is that stuff like `cluster-name` or `discovery` is reflected, but these are not... No errors in logs btw.

Answer (score 0):

I missed it, it is `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes?clear&all`